# Many indexes on the same figure

Tags: captions

How can I put the indexes (a) and (b) on the left side of my figure, at different heights?

```
\begin{figure}[]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{A}

\end{center}
\caption{...}  
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems odd. Why using two different labels for the same object?

You can box the image and then use its height for a `\parbox` with the labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\Figbox
\savebox\Figbox{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\parbox[b][\ht\Figbox][t]{20pt}{(a)\vfill (b)}%
\parbox[b]{\wd\Figbox}{\usebox\Figbox}
\caption{...}  
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to be able to fix the heights of the indexes. Could you do that?

Comment: @Mencia You can place each one inside a `\raisebox` and move them at will: for example, `\raisebox{-10pt}{(a)}`. Or you can use `\vfill`s as in `\vfill (a) \vfill (b) \vfill`.